# Transfer files to/from windows server on aws (lightsail)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-lightsail

I created a windows server 2019 instance using lightsail. Using the rdp client on my home windows 10 machine, I am able to connect.

However, file transfer is disabled. I tried [these instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transfer/latest/userguide/transfer-file.html#winscp) without success using both fileZilla and winSCP - mainly with SFTP with a downloaded private key.

Has anyone managed to connect and transfer files from these clients to a windows server instance? I would prefer a direct connection via FTP in case SFTP for Windows server requires the setup of a dedicated SFTP server to reduce costs.

By the way, I opened all protocols on the machine

Comment: Sorry, but from WHERE are you wanting to transfer to WHERE? You have linked to instructions for an AWS SFTP service that is not relevant to a Windows instance. Are you wanting to upload files to the Windows instance? If so, then you would need to run an FTP server on the instance. The easiest method would probably be to copy the files to S3, and then login to the Windows instance and download the files from S3.

Comment: This is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be able to transfer files, you need to install a FTP service and use a FTP client to be able to connect and exchange files.

You could use Filezilla for both.

You install the server.
Then you need to configure protocols specifications (use a certificate - you can generate one), users (with virtual path and local path).